# Angular2 - Can't detect scrolling events

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to fix a div when scrolling down; for that, I began with the below code, I am facing some weird issue that prevents me from detecting the scrolling behavior. On the below code `console.log('bigger than 50')` does not get printed when scrolling down.

Any ideas why I can't detect the scroll event?

```
@Component({
templateUrl: 'outlet.html',
selector: "app-layout-nav"
})


export class place {


  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])

  onWindowScroll() {
    let number = this.document.body.scrollTop;
    if (number > 50) {
    console.log('bigger than 50')
    this.navIsFixed = true;
   } else if (this.navIsFixed && number < 10) {
      console.log('lower than 50')
      this.navIsFixed = false;
    }
  }

}
```

**Outlet.html**

```
 <div>

 <div id="wrap" [class.fixed]="navIsFixed">
  This should be fixed when it reaches a certain level</div>

  <div>The rest of the long page should show here</div>

 </div>
```

Comment: You need to listen on the div that scrolls, not on window. `window:scroll` is only for when the whole page is scrolled. We would need to see the HTML to and a pointer to the element that is supposed to scroll.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've posted the rest of code. Basically, I believe that it should be `window:scroll` as the user should scroll the window, and a particular `div` on that window will be `fixed` after reaching a certain level of scrolling. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I can't know if you're wrong :D. If you say this is what should happen, then this is probably true. If the page is scrolling, then your `@HostListener()` should capture the scroll events, if it doesn't then not.

Comment: The problem is that `@HostListener()` does not capture the scroll events

Comment: I don't see a way to diagnose it from the code you posted. Can you create Plunker that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I've tried to diagnose with a `console.log('bigger than 50')` which does not get printed in the console

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with the information available.

Answer (score 3):

this might help you to detect scroll events on an element or on window
https://github.com/anasAsh/ngx-scroll-event

### Install

- With NPM
  `npm install ngx-scroll-event --save`
- With Yarn
  `yarn add ngx-scroll-event`

### Usage

Import ScrollEvent and add it to the imports array of your module.

```
// app.module.ts
import { ScrollEventModule } from 'ngx-scroll-event';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    ScrollEventModule,
    ...,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In your template you may now add the `detect-scroll` attribute and `(onScroll)` event to any element.
you can also add `[bottomOffest]` to change when reaching bottom is alert is true, defaults to 100, the value should be a number in pixels.

```
// app.awesome.component.ts

...
import { ScrollEvent } from 'ngx-scroll-event';
...

@Component({
   ...
   template: `...
        <div detect-scroll (onScroll)="handleScroll($event)" [bottomOffest]="200">
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
            <div>Bla bla bla</div>
        <div>
   ...`,
})
export class AwesomeComponent {
  public handleScroll(event: ScrollEvent) {
    console.log('scroll occurred', event.originalEvent);
    if (event.isReachingBottom) {
      console.log(`the user is reaching the bottom`);
    }
    if (event.isWindowEvent) {
      console.log(`This event is hapening on Window not on an element.`);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can bind the scroll event to your container:

```
<div class="container" (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
  <div class="scrollable_content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, on your component:

```
onScroll(event){
  const scrollTop = event.path[0].scrollTop;
}
```